# Определить, различные ли данные в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

есть массив выбранных элементов с id `[1,5]` количество элементов может быть любым. Также есть массив с данными

```
const data = [
    {id:1,type:1},
    {id:3,type:2},
    {id:5,type:2},
]
```

Мне необходимо понять различный ли у этих элементов тип(`type`). Если различный вывести `true` иначе `false`.
Мое решение

```js
const id = [1,5]
const data = [
    {id:1,type:1},
    {id:3,type:2},
    {id:5,type:2},
]

function getValue( array, key) {
    return array.reduce(
        function( prev, item) {
          return ( !prev  &&  item.id == key) ? item.type : prev;
        },
        false
    );
}

const arrayType = id.map(value => getValue(data,value));

function duplicates(arr) {
    return new Set(arr).size !== 1;
}

console.log(duplicates(arrayType))
```

подскажите, может есть более короткое решение, без использования сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Создаём [набор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) айдишников, чтобы не тратить время на поиски
2. Убираем все элементы, у которых `id` нет в списке `ids`. [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
3. Смотрим у всех ли элементов type такой же как у первого. [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Код:

```js
const ids = [1, 5];
const data1 = [
    {id:1,type:1},
    {id:3,type:2},
    {id:5,type:2},
];
const data2 = [
    {id:1,type:2},
    {id:3,type:2},
    {id:5,type:2},
];

const idsSet = new Set(ids);

const isSameType = (objects) =>
    objects
        // Убираем все элементы, у которых id нет в списке ids
        .filter(el => idsSet.has(el.id))
        // Смотрим у всех ли элементов type такой же как у первого
        .every((data, i, arr) => data.type === arr[0].type);

console.log(!isSameType(data1));
console.log(!isSameType(data2));
```

Comment: Кстати у вас, по моему, ответ не правильный, посмотрите в условия: `Если различный вывести true иначе false.`, а у вас наоборот.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Не могу не согласиться, не доглядел :) Но можно по названию понять что функция вернёт `true`, если типы одинаковые. Потому я поправлю только `console.log`, но можно и неравенство поставить в `every`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [
    {id:1,type:1},
    {id:3,type:2},
    {id:5,type:2},
];

let filteredData = data.filter(el => el.id === 1 || el.id === 5);

if (filteredData[0].type === filteredData[1].type)
  console.log('Совпадают')
else 
  console.log('Нет совпадений')
```

Обернуть это всё в отдельную функцию не будет сложно, я думаю.

Comment: дописал вопрос, массив с id может быть любой, для примера привел 2 значения

Answer (score 0):

### Исправление

```js
const id = [1,5]
const data = [
    {id:1,type:1},
    {id:3,type:2},
    {id:5,type:2},
]

function notSameType(ids) {
  let types = []

  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    let _id = ids[i]
    let obj = findObj(_id)

    if(types.includes(obj.type)) {
      return false
    }

    types.push(obj.type)
  }

  return true

  function findObj(id) {
    return data.find(e => e.id === id)
  }
}

console.log(notSameType(id)) // true
console.log(notSameType([1, 5])) // true
console.log(notSameType([3, 5])) // false
console.log(notSameType([1, 3, 5])) // false
```

#### Объяснение

Создаём массив `types`, в нём в будующем мы будем проверять уникальность других типов. Проходимся циклом `for` по массиву, находим нужный объект в массиве `data`, и проверяем его на уникальность, если уже существует, значит возвращаем `false`, а если не существует проходимся дальше, если все типы уникальны, значит возвращаем `true`.

### Короткий ответ

Если вам уж так нравятся короткие ответы, то тогда вот :) (Чисто технически это всего одна строка)

P.S. @EzioMercer вне функции также использовал `Set`, так что прибавляем к нему +1 строку кода :p

```js
const id = [1,5]
const data = [
    {id:1,type:1},
    {id:3,type:2},
    {id:5,type:2},
]

let notSameType = ids => !data
  .filter(e => ids.includes(e.id))
  .every((e, _, arr) => e.type === arr[0].type)


console.log(notSameType(id)) // true
console.log(notSameType([3, 5])) // false
```

#### Объяснение

Убираем все те объекты, которые не имеют `id` который есть в списке `id`. Дальше поверяем все ли `type` равняются этому типу, и далее используя оператор `!` превращаем силой магии винкс все `true` в `false`, а все `false` в `true`, чтобы решение подходило к вопросу.

### Оригинальный Ответ

```js
let data = [
    {id:1,type:1},
    {id:3,type:2},
    {id:5,type:2},
];

function notSameType(id1, id2) {
  let type1 = findObj(id1).type
  let type2 = findObj(id2).type
  
  return type1 !== type2

  function findObj(id) {
    return data.find(e => e.id === id)
  }
}

console.log(notSameType(1, 5)) // true
console.log(notSameType(3, 5)) // false
```

#### Объяснение

Находим объект у который пропорция `id` равна той, которую вы вводим в первый аргумент, далее берём из этого объекта пропорцию `type`, тоже самое со вторым объектом. Если они совпадают, возвращаем `false`, если не совпадают, возвращаем `true`.

Comment: дописал вопрос, массив с id может быть любой, для примера привел 2 значения

Comment: @zxcqwe вы бы сразу уточнили... Ладно, сейчас попытаюсь что-нибудь придумать.

Comment: @zxcqwe обновил ответ, ну как? :)

Comment: ответ @EzioMercer мне нравится больше, в 2 строчке по сути. Но за ваш я тоже поставил голос, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @zxcqwe не факт что у него ответ будет работать быстрее :) Не за что!

Comment: @zxcqwe добавил ещё один ответ, который чисто технически состоит из одной строки.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Это факт что у меня будет работать быстрее, просто у меня будет чутка  больше памяти использоваться :)

Comment: @EzioMercer вы уже тестировали? Можете тогда показать результаты? Чисто из интереса ;)

Comment: @EzioMercer кстати, только что заметил что мой второй ответ и ваш полностью совпадают xd, за исключением того что мой не использует `Set`.

Comment: Нет не тестировал, просто знаю, т.к. как минимум `includes` в цикле - это уже значит экспоненциальное увлечение сложности алгоритма, чего нет у меня